# My Team Fortress 2's userconfig.cfg has gone AWOL

Tags: steam, technical-issues, team-fortress-2, steam-cloud

For whatever reason, I do not have a userconfig.cfg file. Nothing I have done so far has completely restored the file (in order):

- Taking another game's userconfig.cfg file and putting it into the TF2 files (specifically, Fortress Forever),
- Deleting TF2 from my computer via Steam, and
- Manually deleting *all* local TF2 files.

The latter option has done *some* level of restoration, specifically, a one-time deal where my binds, graphic, and other options saved. Everything since then, namely screen resolution, binds, graphic settings, etc. has not saved because the userconfig.cfg is not present.

How do I recover my config file if nothing seems to work?
If it helps, my PC is a "HP Pavilion Desktop - 510-a010"

Comment: Doesn't TF2 use `config.cfg` for user settings?

Comment: If you have game settings you want to ensure on startup, you can also use `autoexec.cfg`

Comment: check you haven't got -autoconfig set in your launch options.

Answer (score 1):

#### Verify Integrity of game files

Usually, missing files can be re-downloaded by using Steam's "Verify Integrity of game files" option.

- Right-click Team Fortress 2 in your library, and select '*Properties*'
- Open the '*Local files*' tab/section of the properties window
- Select "Verify integrity of game files"

---

#### Ensure autoconfig isn't set

As mentioned by user *Smock* in the comments - ensure TF2 **isn't** set to launch with the `-autoconfig` option enabled. If this is enabled, any changes you make to settings will not be saved when you close TF2:

- Right click TF2 and select '*Properties*'
- Open the '*General*' tab/section
- Under '*Launch Options*', remove `--autoconfig`